# Example of a custom Editor component in Handsontable using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, handsontable

I'm using handsontable to build a ReactJS app. For one of the tables, I need to customize the editor component for one of the columns (I'd like to create a multiselect dropdown with checkboxes). I've seen working examples of this done in Vue, but not in ReactJS. When I try to follow

Does anyone have a working example (JSFiddle, CodeSandbox, etc.) of a custom handsontable editor component that I can duplicate? I've tried following the official instructions, but I keep getting an error when I try to run the super.prepare() command and a full working example would be helpful.

Note: I am looking for an example that extends BaseEditorComponent, not one that extends TextEditor or something already prebuilt. We're doing a lot of customization to the editor and we'd like to start from scratch if possible. I was able to get something working when I started from TextEditor, but that's not really what we're looking for.

Thanks!

Hoping to find a live working example, but couldn't find one online for ReactJS.

Comment: Does this help? [React Data Grid Dropdown cell type](https://handsontable.com/docs/react-data-grid/dropdown-cell-type/)

Comment: @Zak - unfortunately no.  The default dropdown editor doesn't include a multiselect option, which is why I need to customize it.